# Not showing graphics in JPanel which is added to another JPanel

Tags: java, swing, jpanel, paintcomponent

When adding a `JPanel` that has graphics to a `JFrame`, it's working fine. But when I try to add a `JPanel`  in which I have added another `JPanel` with graphics, its not showing in the `JFrame`. Please see code below

```
package sample;

import java.awt.Graphics;
import javax.swing.JButton;
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JPanel;

public class Main extends JFrame{
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        new Main();
    }

    public Main(){
        setTitle("Sample");
        setVisible(true);
        setSize(500,500);
        setDefaultCloseOperation(EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        add(new SamplePanel2());
    }
}

class SamplePanel2 extends JPanel{
    public SamplePanel2(){
        add(new JButton("Hi"));
        add(new SamplePanel());
    }
}
class SamplePanel extends JPanel {
    public SamplePanel(){
    }

    protected void paintComponent(Graphics g) {
        super.paintComponent(g);
        g.drawString("HHHHHHHHHHHH", 100, 100);
    }
}
```

Comment: Simply override [getPreferredSize()](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/javax/swing/JComponent.html#getPreferredSize()) and make it return some value like `return new Dimension(300, 300);`, inside your `SamplePanel Class`

Comment: see 'How can i add the JPanel class into JFrame form class in netbeans?' on stackoverflow for more info

Comment: @MaVRoSCy : Mate, you just forgot to put the link to the comment, like in order to put a comment on here, put square brackets [] around here like [here] followed by parenthesis like [here]() and inside the parenthesis paste the URL.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Please do watch the constructor of the `Main` Class, make this your habbit to follow the sequence as shown in this example. First add components to the `JFrame` then only make calls like  `pack(), setSize() or setVisible(...)`, not before that.

Always make it your habbit, that whenever you override `paintcomponent()` method, override `getPreferredSize()` method as well.

And always put calls like `pack()/setVisible(...)` inside the EDT  - Event Dispatch Thread. Please read [Concurrency in Swing](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/concurrency/index.html), for more detail on the topic.

```
import java.awt.Dimension;
import java.awt.Graphics;
import javax.swing.JButton;
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JPanel;

public class Main extends JFrame{
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        new Main();
    }

    public Main(){
        setTitle("Sample");        
        setDefaultCloseOperation(EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        setContentPane(new SamplePanel2());
        pack();        
        setVisible(true);
    }
}

class SamplePanel2 extends JPanel{
    public SamplePanel2(){
        add(new JButton("Hi"));
        add(new SamplePanel());
    }
}
class SamplePanel extends JPanel {
    public SamplePanel(){
    }

    @Override
    public Dimension getPreferredSize()
    {
        return (new Dimension(300, 300));
    }

    @Override
    protected void paintComponent(Graphics g) {
        super.paintComponent(g);
        g.drawString("HHHHHHHHHHHH", 100, 100);
    }
}
```

Comment: @user1508907: Note that the default layout of `JPanel` is [`FlowLayout`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/layout/visual.html#flow).

Comment: You are MOST WELCOME and KEEP SMILING :-)