# Initialization in paintComponent doesn't work

Tags: java, swing

I'm doing some exercise to understand Java and Swing API. Why do I have a nullPointerException in the Disegno constructor? I want to print the coordinates of the two rectangles, but they seem not to be initialitied.

```
import java.awt.*;
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JPanel;

public class Disegno extends JFrame{

    Disegno(){
        this.setSize(500, 500);
        this.setDefaultCloseOperation(this.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        MyPanel aba = new MyPanel();
        this.setContentPane(aba);
        this.setVisible(true);

        System.out.println(aba.rect.blue.x + "-" + aba.rect.blue.y);
        System.out.println(aba.rect.yellow.x + "-" + aba.rect.yellow.y);
    }

    public static void main(String[] args){
        new Disegno();
    }
}

class MyPanel extends JPanel{

    JPanel up, down;
    RectArea rect;

    MyPanel(){
        this.setLayout(new BorderLayout());

        up = new JPanel();
        this.add(up, BorderLayout.NORTH);
        up.setBackground(Color.red);
        up.setVisible(true);

        down = new JPanel();
        down.setBackground(Color.green);
        this.add(down, BorderLayout.SOUTH);
        down.setVisible(true);

        rect = new RectArea();
        this.add(rect, BorderLayout.CENTER);

        this.setVisible(true);
    }
}

class RectArea extends JPanel{

    Rectangle blue, yellow;
    boolean check = false;

    RectArea(){
        super();
        this.setVisible(true);
    }

    public void initRect(){
        blue = new Rectangle(0, 0, 100, 100);
        yellow = new Rectangle(this.getWidth(), this.getHeight(), 100, 100);
        System.out.println("ok");
    }

    @Override
    protected void paintComponent(Graphics g){
        super.paintComponent(g);
        if(check == false){
            this.initRect();
            check = true;
        }

        System.out.println(this.getWidth() + "-" + this.getHeight());
        g.setColor(Color.blue);
        g.fillRect(blue.x, blue.y, blue.width, blue.height);
        g.setColor(Color.yellow);
        g.fillRect(yellow.x - yellow.width, yellow.y - yellow.height, yellow.width, yellow.height);
    }
}
```

Comment: i suspect because contentPane object is not initialised.

Comment: +1 for [sscce](http://sscce.org/).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Others have helpfully suggested ways to detect and avoid the `NullPointerException`. Unfortunately, you can't rely on *when* your implementation of `paintComponent()` will be called. Instead,

- Determine the required geometry as a function of the current widow's size; resize the window in the example below to see how `yellow` seems to *stick* to the bottom right corner.
- Because `MyPanel` contains no components of its own, you should override `getPreferredSize()`, as @nIcE cOw shows [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/11376322/230513).
- Use `pack()` to size the enclosing `Window`.
- Build on the [event dispatch thread](http://download.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/concurrency/initial.html).

Addendum: *I can't understand why you override the method* `getPreferredSize()`.

Subclasses of `JComponent` override [`getPreferredSize()`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/javax/swing/JComponent.html#getPreferredSize%28%29) so that [`pack()`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/awt/Window.html#pack%28%29) can size the `Window` "to fit the preferred size and layouts of its subcomponents." That way you don't have to worry if the user has a different font, for example. `MyPanel` just draws geometric shapes, so you're the boss on preferred size. As discussed [here](https://stackoverflow.com/q/7229226/230513), a demo may use `setPreferredSize()` for convenience, but you should understand the limitations of doing so.

[image]

```
import java.awt.*;
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JPanel;

/**
* @see https://stackoverflow.com/q/11376272/230513
*/
public class Disegno extends JFrame {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        EventQueue.invokeLater(new Runnable() {

            @Override
            public void run() {
                new Disegno();
            }
        });
    }

    Disegno() {
        this.setSize(500, 500);
        this.setDefaultCloseOperation(EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        MyPanel aba = new MyPanel();
        this.add(aba);
        this.pack();
        this.setLocationRelativeTo(null);
        this.setVisible(true);
    }

    class MyPanel extends JPanel {

        private JPanel up, down;
        private RectArea rect;

        MyPanel() {
            super(new BorderLayout());

            up = new JPanel();
            up.setBackground(Color.red);
            this.add(up, BorderLayout.NORTH);

            rect = new RectArea();
            this.add(rect, BorderLayout.CENTER);

            down = new JPanel();
            down.setBackground(Color.green);
            this.add(down, BorderLayout.SOUTH);
        }

        @Override
        public Dimension getPreferredSize() {
            return new Dimension(320, 240);
        }
    }

    class RectArea extends JPanel {

        private Rectangle blue = new Rectangle(0, 0, 100, 100);
        private Rectangle yellow = new Rectangle(0, 0, 100, 100);

        @Override
        protected void paintComponent(Graphics g) {
            super.paintComponent(g);
            System.out.println(this.getWidth() + " x " + this.getHeight());
            g.setColor(Color.blue);
            g.fillRect(blue.x, blue.y, blue.width, blue.height);

            g.setColor(Color.yellow);
            int dx = getWidth() - yellow.width;
            int dy = getHeight() - yellow.height;
            g.fillRect(dx, dy, yellow.width, yellow.height);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: +1 again, for all in the info. I just realized, that the OP can make different object of the same `RectArea` Class, to use as different colour Rectangles, instead of creating Blue, Yellow inside the RectArea Class.

Comment: Good insight; feel free to use my example if you update your answer to address this.

Comment: Thank you for the answer. I have another question. I can't understand why you override the method getPreferredSize(). Shouldn't MyPanel have the same size of the JFrame? MyPanel contains all the others Panel, isn't it? (Sorry for my english)

Comment: It doesn't have to, as shown in these [examples](http://stackoverflow.com/q/9849950/230513). I also tried to explain more above.

Answer (score 2):

You never called `rect.initRect();` anywhere, that's why you getting error related to `NullPointerException` at those `System.out.println() lines`. Why you using `panelObject.setVisible(true)` inside each class, first add them to the `JPanel` and simply call `setVisible(...)` on the `JFrame` that will do. Here watch your modified code with the said thingies, working as expected :

```
import java.awt.*;
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JPanel;

public class Disegno extends JFrame{

    Disegno(){
        this.setSize(500, 500);
        this.setDefaultCloseOperation(this.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        MyPanel aba = new MyPanel();
        this.setContentPane(aba);
        this.setVisible(true);

        System.out.println(aba.rect.blue.x + "-" + aba.rect.blue.y);
        System.out.println(aba.rect.yellow.x + "-" + aba.rect.yellow.y);
    }

    public static void main(String[] args){
        new Disegno();
    }
}

class MyPanel extends JPanel{

    JPanel up, down;
    RectArea rect;

    MyPanel(){
        this.setLayout(new BorderLayout());

        up = new JPanel();
        this.add(up, BorderLayout.NORTH);
        up.setOpaque(true);
        up.setBackground(Color.red);

        down = new JPanel();
        down.setOpaque(true);
        down.setBackground(Color.green);
        this.add(down, BorderLayout.SOUTH);

        rect = new RectArea();
        rect.initRect();
        this.add(rect, BorderLayout.CENTER);
    }
}

class RectArea extends JPanel{

    Rectangle blue, yellow;
    boolean check = false;

    RectArea(){
        super();
        setOpaque(true);
    }

    public void initRect(){
        blue = new Rectangle(0, 0, 100, 100);
        yellow = new Rectangle(this.getWidth(), this.getHeight(), 100, 100);
        System.out.println("ok");
    }

    @Override
    protected void paintComponent(Graphics g){
        super.paintComponent(g);
        if(check == false){
            this.initRect();
            check = true;
        }

        System.out.println(this.getWidth() + "-" + this.getHeight());
        g.setColor(Color.blue);
        g.fillRect(blue.x, blue.y, blue.width, blue.height);
        g.setColor(Color.yellow);
        g.fillRect(yellow.x - yellow.width, yellow.y - yellow.height, yellow.width, yellow.height);
    }
}
```

If you would write a `System.out.println()` inside the `intiRect()` you will know, the lines which are giving you errors are being called before the `paintComponent(...)` method itself. So it appears to me, that you have to take that logic out of the `paintComponent(...)` method and keep it somewhere else, or else remove those lines, if you don't need them.

Comment: +1 for [sscce](http://sscce.org/). I've proposed an [alternative](http://stackoverflow.com/a/11377526/230513), citing one of you examples.

Answer (score 1):

You are trying to access `aba.rect.blue` and `aba.rect.yellow` in your `Disegno` constructor, however these are not initialized until `RectArea.paintComponent` is called, so it throws an NPE.

Comment: but the paintComponent is called, the System.out.println(this.getWidth() + "-" + this.getHeight()); in it prints!!!

Comment: @Amk: Do you have a stack trace? Does it tell you which line the NPE occurs on?

Answer (score 1):

Are you sure that your code gave a NullPointerException .......??

**Because when i ran your code, it worked fine...**

**Output:**

```
ok
484-442
```

Comment: I hope you are executing the right code... i mean check the output..is my output matching your expected one ??

Comment: +1 for reporting. Because the original is incorrectly synchronized, you could _both_ be running the same code and getting different results. This [alternative](http://stackoverflow.com/a/11377526/230513) should behave consistently.